# Xamarin forms android image is not getting compressed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I'm working on xamarin forms project. I'm taking images from gallery and uploading those to server. My back-end is parse backend where we can not upload files having size more than 1MB. So, I'm trying to compress the image so that every time the image size is less than 1MB.
Mentioned below is my code :-

```
protected override async void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
            return;

        try {
            var mediafile = await intent.GetMediaFileExtraAsync (Forms.Context);

            // get byte[] from file stream
            byte[] byteData = ReadFully (mediafile.GetStream ());

            byte[] resizedImage = ResizeAndCompressImage (byteData, 60, 60, mediafile);

            var imageStream = new ByteArrayContent (resizedImage);
            imageStream.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue ("attachment") {
                FileName = Guid.NewGuid () + ".Png"
            };

            var multi = new MultipartContent ();
            multi.Add (imageStream);
            HealthcareProfessionalDataClass lDataClass = HealthcareProfessionalDataClass.Instance;
            lDataClass.Thumbnail = multi;
            App.mByteArrayOfImage = byteData;

            MessagingCenter.Send<IPictureTaker,string> (this, "picturetaken", mediafile.Path);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.PrintStackTrace ();
        } catch (Java.Lang.Exception e) {
            e.PrintStackTrace ();
        }
    }

public static byte[] ReadFully (System.IO.Stream input)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream ()) {
            input.CopyTo (ms);
            return ms.ToArray ();
        }
    }


public static byte[] ResizeAndCompressImage (byte[] imageData, float width, float height, MediaFile file)
    {
        try {
            // Load the bitmap
            var options = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
            options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
            options.InMutable = true;
            BitmapFactory.DecodeFile (file.Path, options);
            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.InSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize (options, (int)width, (int)height);
            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;

            var originalBitMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (imageData, 0, imageData.Length, options);

            var resizedBitMap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap (originalBitMap, (int)width, (int)height, false);

            if (originalBitMap != null) {
                originalBitMap.Recycle ();
                originalBitMap = null;
            }
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream ()) {

                resizedBitMap.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, ms);

                if (resizedBitMap != null) {
                    resizedBitMap.Recycle ();
                    resizedBitMap = null;
                }
                return ms.ToArray ();
            }
        } catch (Java.Lang.Exception e) {
            e.PrintStackTrace ();
            return null;
        }
    }

public static int calculateInSampleSize (BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        // Raw height and width of image
        int height = options.OutHeight;
        int width = options.OutWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 16;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            int halfHeight = height / 2;
            int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                   && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

But the problem is my image is not getting compressed.I'm not able to upload an image having size = 2MB and I want to upload images having size at-least 30 MB. Also I've observed that calculateInSampleSize always returns 16 as inSampleSize which is default one.

Please let me know if there's any issue in my code.

Comment: i think this will be helpful on managing and compressing big images http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/ if not please excuse me

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very complicated and convoluted way of doing it. Here's a more concise sample that should help you resize your images:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    var stream = this.Resize(data.Data, 60, 60);
    // Send the stream to Parse
}

private Stream Resize(Android.Net.Uri uri, float maxWidth, float maxHeight)
{
    var scale = 1;
    using (var rawStream = this.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(f))
    using (var options = new BitmapFactory.Options { InJustDecodeBounds = true })
    {
        BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(rawStream, null, options);

        while(options.OutWidth / scale / 2 > maxWidth || 
              options.OutHeight / scale / 2 > maxHeight)
        {
            scale *= 2;
        }
    }

    using (var options = new BitmapFactory.Options { InSampleSize = scale })
    using (var bitmap = f.GetBitmap(options))
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        return memoryStream;
    }
}
```

Regarding why you are seeing `InSampleSize = 16`, my guess is that your image's height or width are less than 1920 (which is `60 * 2 * 16`) and since you are using `&&` in the while loop, the greater check for that side fails and thus, you never enter the while body.

Additionally, if you are looking to create smaller images, compressing them as Jpeg is a much better approach than using png's.